# hCard address with a 'care of' (c/o) element

Tags: html, microformats, hcard

Say I've got an address like this:

> Foobar Widget Team
>   c/o ACME Widgets Inc.
>   123 The Drive
>   Someplace Town
>   BN1 1AB

I want to mark this up as an hCard but I am not sure what class names I should apply to the two organisation names. Foobar Widget Team might be a group of employees who get together and run a local football team, supported and sponsored by ACME but not officially an organisational unit of ACME - they're just using ACME as the mailing address.

So what is the best way of expressing this using hCard? I thought of using the AGENT property, but that seems to apply to a person rather than an organisation acting on behalf of another. Organization-unit isn't quite right either as, strictly speaking, Foobar Widget Team isn't a unit of ACME. How else might I mark this up?

Answer (score 0):

I think that AGENT would be correct to use for an organization as well; the only requirement is that it is something that is separately addressable which can act on behalf of the the intended recipient.

The other option would just be to use the free-form LABEL field for the address of Foobar Widget Team, including everything from the "c/o" to the end. Given that there aren't likely to be a lot of consumers that will get any value out of specifying the relationship precisely, just putting it into a freeform text value will allow simple programs that just extract the address to produce an address label that contains the right information, without having to understand what the "c/o" line means.